# A curious martingale

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Does there exist an almost surely continuous martingale $X$ with $X_t \to +\infty$ almost surely?

**Remark:** Note that such a martingale exists in discrete time, or equivalently in continuous time if the a.s. continuity requirement is dropped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. see [Martingale Convergence](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/20/martingale-convergence/)

> Theorem 4 Let X be a continuous martingale. Then, almost surely, one of the following is satisfied
>
> - $X_\infty=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t$ exists and is finite.
> - $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t=\infty$ and $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t=-\infty$. In this case, the process hits every value in $\mathbb R$ at arbitrarily large times.

Comment: Wow, very interesting theorem. The link is not working however, could you rectify that?

Comment: I suppose the proof is via the Dambin-Dubins-Schwartz theorem, the two possibilities correspond to the time change being bounded or unbounded respectively. (Edit: it seems the post provides an alternate proof.)

Comment: I fixed the link.

Comment: The result that you linked follows immediately from Lemma 5 in those notes. However, I cannot make any sense of the 5-line proof of that Lemma 5, which in particular has this: "$n-1_{\{\tau_n > 0\}}X^{\tau_n}$ is a nonnegative supermartingale". Here  $\tau_n:=\inf\left\{t\in{\mathbb R}_+\colon X_t\ge n\right\}$. First here, $X^{\tau_n}$  is undefined when $\tau_n=\infty$. Second, assuming that $\tau_n<\infty$ a.s., we have $n-1_{\{\tau_n > 0\}}X^{\tau_n}=n\,1(X_0\ge n)$, which is not a supermartingale.

Comment: Previous comment continued: If there was a typo and the intention was to say "$n-1_{\{\tau_n <\infty\}}X^{\tau_n}$ is a nonnegative supermartingale", that would not be true either; actually, $n-1_{\{\tau_n <\infty\}}X^{\tau_n}=n\,1_{\{\tau_n =\infty\}}$ is a nonnegative **sub**martingale.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Do we both understand $X^{\tau_n}$ to be the process stopped at $\tau_n$? i.e., $X_t^{\tau_n} := X_{\min(t, \tau_n)}$. I assumed that was what the author meant but I'm not 100% sure. But anyway in that case $X^{\tau_n}$ is well defined when $\tau_n = \infty$, its just equal to $X$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Also, since $X$ is assumed to be a submartingale, isnt $-X$, and hence $n - X$ a supermartingale? And then the stopped process will also be a supermartingale.

Comment: @NateRiver : Thank you for your response. I see now that I misunderstood the notation, in at least two places.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Glad that cleared it up!

Answer (score 6):

I think Iosif's Fatou lemma argument can be fixed, as follows.

Assume without loss of generality that $X_0 = 0$.

Suppose to the contrary that $X_t \to +\infty$ a.s.  Then it must be that $\inf_{t \ge 0} X_t > -\infty$ a.s.  Choose a number $b < 0$ sufficiently negative that the event $A_b = \{ \inf_{t \ge 0} X_t > b\}$ has positive probability.  Let $T_b = \inf\{ t : X_t \le b\}$ be the corresponding stopping time, and let $Y_t = X_{t \wedge T_b}$.  By optional stopping, $Y_t$ is again a martingale, so $E[Y_t] = E[Y_0] = 0$ for all $t$.  Note also that on the event $A_b$, we have $Y_t = X_t$ for all $t$ and so $Y_t \to +\infty$ a.s. on $A_b$.

On the other hand, $Y_t \ge b$ (by continuity!) so we can apply Fatou's lemma to $Y_t$, concluding that $E[\liminf Y_t] \le E[Y_0] = 0$.  But $\liminf Y_t = +\infty$ a.s. on $A_b$, where $P(A_b) > 0$, so this is absurd.

Note that we used the continuity in a subtle way: if $X_t$ had not been continuous, we could still define the stopped martingale $Y_t$, but we would not be able to say $Y_t \ge b$ (because $X_t$ could cross $b$ for the first time by jump).  In such a case, $Y_t$ could end up being unbounded below, and the argument fails.