# On the convergence of a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, limits-and-convergence, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion and let $A$ be the process defined by :
$$\forall \ t\geq 0: \quad A_t := \int_0^t\left(1 + e^{W_s}\right)\mathrm{d}s$$

and for $t\geq 0$, we define the following stopping time:
$$\sigma_t := \inf \{s\geq 0: \ A_s > t\}$$

Notice that a.s:
$$\forall \ t\geq 0: \quad \sigma_t \leq t$$

Now, define the martingale $M$ as a time changed Brownian motion, i.e. $M := \left(W_{A_t}\right)_{t\geq 0}$. Can we prove that $M$ goes to infinity in probability ? Thanks.

Comment: actually, are you sure this is the right martingale you have in mind? Shouldn't it be $M_{t}=B_{A_{t}}$ equivalently $M_{\sigma_{t}}=B_{t}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is actually $M_t:= B_{A_t}$. I have edited the original post. Can we prove that M is a true martingale?

Comment: every Itô integral has zero expectation and so the increment disappears.

Comment: That’s true, it might require a localization argument as the intregrand is not bounded, but it can be proven. Thank you !

Comment: This question is surprinzingly close to the conjecture I made in my partial answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460751/another-curious-martingale/460775#comment1194972_460775 However, I think that there is a typo here. The martingale that I considered is $(X_{\sigma_t})_{t \ge 0}$, and not $(W_{A_t})$. It do not know whether this last process is a martingale.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks for your comment. It is actually very close and interesting as well! Indeed, it's not necessarily a true martingale. We can open another thread to study the convergence of $\left(W_{\sigma_t}\right)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we study

$$M_{t}=B_{A_{t}}\stackrel{d}{=}\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{1+e^{W_{s}}}dW_{s}.$$

First, as mentioned [Martingale Convergence](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/20/martingale-convergence/) here

> Theorem 4 Let X be a continuous martingale. Then, almost surely, one of the following is satisfied
>
> - $X_\infty=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t$ exists and is finite.
> - $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t=\infty$ and $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t=-\infty$. In this case, the process hits every value in $\mathbb R$ at arbitrarily large times.

By Itô isometry we have

$$E[M^{2}_{t}]=\int^t 1+Ee^{W_{s}}ds=\int^t 1+e^{\frac{s}{2}}ds \to +\infty,$$

which also shows that $<M>_{\infty}=\infty$. In general for continuous martingales we have that

"$X_\infty=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t$ exists and is finite" iff $<X>_{\infty}<\infty.$

The left-right direction that is relevant here is as follows: we use the stopping time $\tau_{n}:=\inf\{t\geq 0: |X_{t}|\geq n\}$ and the bound $$E[<X>_{t\wedge \tau_{n}}]=E[X^{2}_{t\wedge \tau_{n}}]\leq n^{2}$$

to get that the event $\{\sup|X_t|<\infty\}=\bigcup_{n}\{\sup|X_t|<n\}$ implies that the finiteness $<X>_{\infty}<\infty$. (For the other direction we can use instead $\tau_{n}:=\inf\{t\geq 0: <X>_{t}\geq n\}$.)

So we can't have the first case in the above theorem, because it would give a contradiction and so we have the second case.

For the "in probability" part, we will use a reverse tail inequality: when $\mathbb {E} [X]=0,\,\mathbb {E} [X^{2}]=1$ then

$$\Pr(X\geq 0)\geq {\frac {2{\sqrt {3}}-3}{\mathbb {E} [X^{4}]}},$$

from [Berger's "The Fourth Moment Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality). By symmetry of Brownian motion we write

$$P[M_{t}\leq 0]=P[0\leq \tilde{M}_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{1+e^{-W_{s}}}dW_{s}].$$

We still have $E[\tilde{M}_{t}]=0$ and we will need the fourth moment bound

$$E\left(\int f dW\right)^{4}\leq c_{2}\left(\int Ef^{2} ds\right)^{2},$$

from Corollary 4 in ["Notes on the Itô Calculus" by Steven P. Lalley](http://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/385/ItoIntegral.pdf). Therefore, for $X_{t}:=\tilde{M}_{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{E[\tilde{M}_{t}^{2}]}}$ and using the above bound we get

$$P[\tilde{M}_{t}\geq 0]\geq  {\frac {2{\sqrt {3}}-3}{\mathbb {E} [X^{4}]}}\geq  \frac {2{\sqrt {3}}-3}{c_{2}}>0$$

for all $t>0$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Now that we have convergence to infinity in the $L^2$ sense, does that imply convergence in probability even though the limit is infinite?

Comment: it does not converge to infinity. See the theorem I cited. The infinite L2 shows that we don't have finite limit and thus we have the second case.

Comment: sorry I didn’t read it well, thanks.

Comment: If I have understood well the theorem, it rules out almost sure convergence of continuous martingales to infinity. Do you think that convergence to infinity in the probability sense might still hold?

Comment: the limsup/liminf convergence is almost surely which is stronger than probability.

Comment: Yes that’s true. What I wanted to say is: can we find a continuous martingale, for which almost sure convergence to infinity doesn’t hold, but it holds in probability in the sense that, $\forall \ \varepsilon, A > 0, \ \exists t_0 > 0, \ \forall t \geq t_0, \ \mathbb{P}(M_t < A) \leq \varepsilon$

Comment: no because it would contradict the almost-sure convergence. But you can extract a subsequence see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461027/on-the-convergence-of-a-martingale

Comment: "the limsup/liminf convergence is almost surely which is stronger than probability". What do you mean by this? Why does the almost sure limsup/liminf "convergence" to $\pm\infty$ prevent $X_t$ from converging to $\infty$ in probability?

Comment: I added more details to clarify. Here we use the conclusion of the second case that due to continuity, $X$ hits every value repeatedly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "given every $t>0$, we have that $X_{t}$ will hit zero in finite time , we write this as $\tau_{0}\circ t<\infty$." (Can you rewrite everything **formally** and in detail?) More generally, I do not see why "$X$ hits every value repeatedly" would prevent $X_t$ from converging to $\infty$ in probability.

Comment: I added some more details. If wrong, any feedback from anyone is appreciated. There might be some shorter way that I didn't find.

Comment: @IosifPinelis He proved that $\forall t > 0, \mathbb{P}(M_t \leq 0) \geq \frac{2\sqrt{3} - 3}{c_2}: = \delta$. Suppose that $M$ converges in probability in the sense that I’ve mentionned above. Noticing that $\delta \leq \mathbb{P}(M_t \leq 0) \leq \mathbb{P}(M_t \leq A)\leq \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ and taking $\varepsilon \in (0, \delta)$ yields a contradiction.