# On martingale convergence

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a martingale with continuous paths. It was previously shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/460543/36721) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/460567/36721) that then it is impossible that $X_t\to\infty$ almost surely as $t\to\infty$.

Is it possible that there exist a nonrandom sequence $(t_k)$ in $[0,\infty)$ converging to $\infty$ such that $X_{t_k}\to\infty$ almost surely as $k\to\infty$? That is,

> do there exist a martingale $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ with continuous paths and a nonrandom sequence $(t_k)$ in $[0,\infty)$ converging to $\infty$ such that $X_{t_k}\to\infty$ almost surely as $k\to\infty$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can construct a continuous local martingale $X$ such that $X(n) = n$ almost surely. Indeed, for $t < 1$, set $Y(t) = B(t/(1-t))$ for $B$ a Brownian motion and then $X(t) = Y(t \wedge \tau)$ with $\tau = \inf\{t>0:Y(t) = 1\}$. Since $Y$ is a continuous local martingale and $\tau$ is a stopping time, $X$ is a continuous local martingale such that $X(1) = 1$ almost surely. It then suffices to concatenate independent copies of that process.

One can tweak the construction to get a genuine martingale by replacing $\tau$ by $\tau_n = \inf \{t>0:Y(t) \in \{1,-n^2\}\}$ over the $n$th interval. The fact that one still has $\lim_{n \to \infty} X(n) = +\infty$ in this case is a consequence of the fact that, by the martingale property, $\mathbb{P}(X(n+1) \neq X(n)+1) = 1/(1+n^2)$ which only happens finitely many times by Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited it to fix what I think was a typo.

Comment: So that I understand, how is $X$ a martingale?  It seems like we have $E[X(1)] = 1 \ne 0 = X(0)$.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving You are right of course, I should have said that it is a local martingale (which I think was somewhat implicit in the question). Fixed.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Did you want a martingale or a local martingale?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving I've tweaked the construction to get a genuine (even bounded) martingale.

Comment: Nice, that seems to work!  And still $\liminf_{t \to \infty} X(t) = -\infty$ because $Y(t)$ hitting $-2n$ happens infinitely many times.

Answer (score 3):

If the answer to Nate Rivers' last question, and sorry that im not just linking to it, is yes, and people seem to think it is, then you can have convergence in probability to infinity, from which a sequence converging pointwise can be extracted  $$$$
I am editing this comment because the machine suggested doing it rather than posting another answer. $$$$
On the interval (n-1,n) represent  an r.v. using the incremental brownian motion that has the distribution 1 with prob $1-2^{-n}$  and A with prob $2^{-n}$ where A is chosen to  give the r.v mean 0.  Then, stringing them together, the  martingale converges to infinity at integer points because negative values occur only finitely often.

Comment: Yes, this was the motivation for my question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Am I right that you want to use this result as an auxiliary lemma to prove the original claim on convergence in probability?

Comment: @NateRiver : This is correct.

Comment: It seems like we can predict the target using the value at $n-1/2$, well enough that this isn’t a martingale.  Is that right?  That is, it looks like a martingale if we apply the definition only at integer values, but not if we apply the martingale definition at all intermediate values.